# Bluetooth data transfert and device connexion

Tags: sqlite, share, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to implement a bluetooth funtion for my app. I want to send byte array from my app to another device using bluetoth. I Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) tutorial but:

1. i can't get a list of paired devices.
2. I can't connect to any device (Because of 1.) No device is listed. And also want data transfert to occur on item click
3. How can i tranfer jason file using bluetooth (ConnectedThred method.)

Any Help?